# Close a form when another form closes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

This should be simple, but I can't get it to work. I've searched SO and Google and amazingly I haven't found the answer. All I want to do is close one form when another form closes. The second form is opened on a button click. When Form1 closes, Form2 should also close. Form2 may not be open so we need to check to see if it's open first.

This is what I've been working with:

```
Private Sub frm_scu_config_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    ' this isn't working
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frm_scu_report_display).Any Then

        Dim frmConfig As frm_scu_report_display

        ' Open the config form and pass the list of turbines
        frmConfig = New frm_scu_report_display()
        frmConfig.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Form2 IsNot Nothing Then Form2.Close`

Comment: Use boolean variable as a flag ..

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix. If I throw a message box in the if statement, it correctly identifies if the second form is open, it just doesn't close it.

Comment: please show the button click - I suspect an issue of scope or implicit instancing

Comment: The normal way the logic goes is, open form 2 as a dialog, close when closed. However if your case is more complex, you can have a delegate and then register form_closing event on the form you are watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the better half of the answer in that LINQ query, but then you create a new instance of `frm_scu_report_display` and try to close this (unopened) instance.
If I didn't get it wrong, it should work if you stay on the path you already had right:

```
    While Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frm_scu_report_display).Any
        Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frm_scu_report_display).First.Close()
    End While
```

Comment: Thank you @KekuSemau! That worked perfectly. Thanks also for explaining my error in logic also. :)

Comment: Don't try this in production.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wouldn't use this either, just showing how it would work with what he already had...